# Порядок следования качественных прилагательных

Tags: согласование, грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли правило, устанавливающее порядок следования качесвенных прилагательных, которые относятся к одному существительному? Например, объемные газопроницаемые осадительные электроды или газопроницаемые объемные осадительные электроды?

Answer (score 1):

Ближе всего к существительному располагается прилагательное, обозначающее общий родовой признак, а затем следуют прилагательные, обозначающие частные видовые признаки. Поэтому всё зависит от классификации предметов.

Что касается данной темы, то лучше ориентироваться на техническую литературу с уже готовыми решениями, например:

Kv - отношение объема **газопроницаемого объемного осадительного** электрода к объему газового канала электрофильтра.